# Passing method child's component to another 'external' component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs, coding and this is my first time posting here! So, I'm trying to build a Todo app in ReactJs. I have four components.

the first compo. is App.js - the parent one

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TaskTodo from './TaskTodo';
import './App.css';
import TaskDisplayed from "./TaskDisplayed";

class App extends Component {
render() {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1 className="App-title">Hey, i'm the header! </h1>
            </header>
            <div className="App-intro">
                <TaskTodo/>
            </div>

            <div className="App-right">
                <TaskDisplayed/>
            </div>
        </div>
       );
    }
 }

export default App;
```

---

TaskTodo.js - which is the parent of the TodoItems.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';


export default class TaskTodo extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: []
    };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
};


addItem(e) {
    const itemArray = this.state.items;

    if (this._inputElement.value !== "") {
        itemArray.unshift(
            {
                text: this._inputElement.value,
                key: Date.now()
            }
        );

        this.setState({
            items: itemArray
        });

        this._inputElement.value = "";
    }

    e.preventDefault();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="todoListMain">
            <div className="header">
                <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                    <input type="text" ref={(a) => this._inputElement = a}
                           placeholder="Add a list">
                    </input>
                </form>
            </div>
            <TodoItems entries={this.state.items}/>

        </div>
     );
  }
}
```

---

TodoItems.js - the child of the TaskTodo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class TodoItems extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.createTasks = this.createTasks.bind(this);
}

handleClick = (text) => {
    console.log(text);
}
createTasks(item) {
    return <li key={item.key}><a onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.key, item.text)} href={'#about'}>#{item.text}</a></li>
}

render() {
    const todoEntries = this.props.entries;
    const listItems = todoEntries.map(this.createTasks);

    return (
        <ul className="theList">
            {listItems}
        </ul>
     );
  }
};

 export default TodoItems;
```

What I need to do, is how I can pass the handleClick method (a child's of TaskTodo) to an 'external' component - TaskDisplayed.js; or how I can track when the user click to a listed item? Please pardon me for this unprofessional way of  asking! But, I truly need to get in track with ReactJS! Thanks!

p.s. The above code I found online, so thanks for that :D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the onClick event handler in the parent component and pass it to the child as a prop.

See [How to pass an event handler to a child component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904795/how-to-pass-an-event-handler-to-a-child-component-in-react)

In this case, you would want to define it in the App component since that is the parent of the two components that need to communicate.