# How do I call an event handler or method in a child component from a parent?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, components, material-ui

I'm trying to implement something similar to the Floating Action Button (FAB) in the Material-UI docs:

https://material-ui.com/demos/buttons/#floating-action-buttons

They have something like:

```
<SwipeableViews>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item One</TabContainer>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Two</TabContainer>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Three</TabContainer>
</SwipeableViews>
{
  fabs.map((fab, index) => (
    <Zoom>
      <Fab>{fab.icon}</Fab>
    </Zoom>
  ));
}
```

I have something like:

```
<SwipeableViews>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>
    <ListOfThingsComponent />
  </TabContainer>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Two</TabContainer>
  <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Three</TabContainer>
</SwipeableViews>
{
  fabs.map((fab, index) => (
    <Zoom>
      <Fab onClick={ListOfThingsComponent.Add???}>
        Add Item to List Component
      </Fab>
    </Zoom>
  ));
}
```

My `ListOfThingsComponent` originally had an `Add` button and it worked great. But I wanted to follow the FAB approach for it like they had in the docs. In order to do this, the Add button would then reside outside of the child component. So how do I get a button from the parent to call the Add method of the child component?

I'm not sure how to actually implement the Add Item to List click event handler given that my list component is inside the tab, while the FAB is outside the whole tab structure.

As far as I know I can either:

1. find a way to connect parent/child to pass the event handler through the levels (e.g. [How to pass an event handler to a child component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904795/how-to-pass-an-event-handler-to-a-child-component-in-react))
2. find a way to better compose components/hierarchy to put the responsibility at the right level (e.g. remove the component and put it in the same file with `this` in scope using function components?)

I've seen people use `ref` but that just feels hacky. I'd like to know how it *should* be done in React. It would be nice if the example went just a bit further and showed where the event handling should reside for the FABs.

thanks in advance, as always, I'll post what I end up doing

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. There are a lot of possible ways to organize functionality and your example doesn't currently provide any insight as to the nature of the custom component or what kind of action the FAB executes. In some cases there wouldn't need to be any direct interaction between the two. It depends a lot on your overall state management approach.

Comment: Thanks @RyanCogswell, I've updated my question to be more specific. If you have any ideas on how you would manage the state of a list, while having the add button outside the child component, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you expect the clicks to do. Will they only change the state of the given item or will they perform changes outside of that hierarchy? Will a fab be present in every single Tab or you're not sure?

I would think in most cases you're better off doing what you were doing before. Write a CustomComponent for each Tab and have it handle the FAB by itself. The only case in which this could be a bad approach is if you know beforehand that the FAB's callback will make changes up and out of the CustomComponent hierarchy, because in that case you may end up with a callback mess in the long run (still, nothing that global state management couldn't fix).

**Edit after your edit:** Having a button call a function that is inside a child component is arguably impossible to do in React (without resorting to Refs or other mechanisms that avoid React entirely) because of its one-way data flow. That function has to be somewhere in common, in this case in the component that mounts the button and the ListOfThings component. The button would call that method which would change the state in the "Parent" component, and the new state gets passed to the ListOfThings component via props:

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    list: []
  };

  clickHandler = () => {
    // Update state however you need
    this.setState({
      list: [...this.state.list, 'newItem']
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SwipeableViews>
          <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>
            <ListOfThingsComponent list={this.state.list /* Passing the state as prop */}/>
          </TabContainer>
          <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Two</TabContainer>
          <TabContainer dir={theme.direction}>Item Three</TabContainer>
        </SwipeableViews>
        {
          fabs.map((fab, index) => (
            <Zoom>
              <Fab onClick={this.clickHandler /* Passing the click callback */}> 
                Add Item to List Component
              </Fab>
            </Zoom>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If you truly need your hierarchy to stay like that, you have to use this method or some form of global state management that the ListOfThingsComponent can read from.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DoHn! My example is just a list of things in a child component, and the FAB would just be the Add button, since that is the main action. The Material-UI docs just have the buttons show up outside the tabs structure, so it isn't evident how they would envision someone using this structure.

Comment: ok, that is making more sense, care to update your answer with code? if so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: ok this makes sense now, i come from a two way binding style front end framework and it is hard to think like react... one. way. binding. recompose after updates. Thanks!

Comment: just sucks that `newItem` is currently created in the child component... will have to bring that up a level somehow.

Comment: I must say that there is certainly a way to structure you components better. If you create the new item inside the ListOfThingsComponent and use that new item only there, it's not worth it to have the fab outside of it. I'm sure you have your reasons for keeping it outside, but, for what I've understood from your code, it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: or rather that i need to save the new item FROM the child, and not expect the parent to make the call, i can access the API from the child code for the submit of a new item

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189971/discussion-between-nateous-and-dohn).