# How to pass the 'onClick' function to child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a very generic Modal that can get different header, body and footer, but also different arguments for their Reactstrap components (I'm using Reactstrap to create the Modal but the question needn't be specific to solve a Reactstrap problem).

My `GenericModal.js` code looks like:

```
class GenericModal extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return(
        <Reactstrap.Modal {...this.props.other} />
            <Reactstrap.ModalHeader {...this.props.headerArgs}>{this.props.header}</Reactstrap.ModalHeader>
            <Reactstrap.ModalBody {...this.props.bodyArgs}>{this.props.body}</Reactstrap.ModalBody>
            <Reactstrap.ModalFooter {...this.props.footerArgs}>{this.props.footer}</Reactstrap.ModalFooter>
        </Reactstrap.Modal>);
    }
}
```

And so I call this class like this:

```
<GenericCard {...{other: other, headerArgs: headerArgs, bodyArgs: bodyArgs, footerArgs: footerArgs, 
              cardheader:header, cardbody:body, cardfooter:footer}} />
```

Now I know that this method works because I've tried it with `className`, for example:

```
const bodyArgs = {className: 'my-5'};
```

I want to also be able to pass an `onClick` function - but not merely the function (as we can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39904795)), but the whole thing: `onClick=foo()`.

I'm having a bit of a problem understanding how I can put the `onClick` method inside a json-style format like I did with `className`.

I can't write an anonymous function for the `onClick` inside `const bodyArgs = {...}`, and writing it as

```
const bodyArgs = {onClick: {foo}};
```

Provides an undefined `foo`. I also can't put `this.foo` because it's an unexpected syntax as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, found the solution moments after I posted this.

Just didn't need the `{}` curly brackets.

```
const bodyArgs = {onClick: this.foo};
```

Does the job.

Thought I'd keep it here in case anyone stumbles into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you have explained but I cannot fully know without the whole example. Here is a working bit of code and a codesandbox link of what you are tying to do.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class ClickExecutor extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Click Executor</h4>
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.bodyArgs.alert1()}>One</button>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.bodyArgs.alert2()}>Two</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class GenericModal extends React.Component {
  alert1 = () => {
    alert("Alert 1");
  };

  alert2 = () => {
    alert("Alert 2");
  };

  render() {
    const bodyArgs = {
      alert1: this.alert1,
      alert2: this.alert2
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Generic Modal</h1>
        <ClickExecutor
          {...{
            bodyArgs: bodyArgs,
            otherProps: "other various properties ..."
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GenericModal />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Working Demo LINK : https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-frost-rj1vb

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't explicit enough: the point is **not** to pass a function to an already defined `onClick` in the child, but to pass the `onClick` *itself*. As I've shown in my answer :)